# How to sort JSON with multiple different parameters from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

For a school I am creating a program that uses JSON and JavaScript to pull back data onto a webpage. I understand how to sort through the array and pull back values of they match. Lets says I have this JSON.

```
{"name":"Michael","age":30,"bday":"05/12/1982"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30,"bday":"02/21/1992"}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19,"bday":"12/07/1972"}
```

How would I be able to have a name input, age select and a birthday input that I could sort by any combination of those being used.

Say everyone that is 30 and born on 02/21/1992, or everyone that is 30? I want to be able to sort by every possible combination of data entry and I do not want to just use a bunch of if() statements.

Comment: do you want sorting or filtering?

Comment: are your displaying this data into table like datatable or you need this for other  ?

Comment: Sorry, i guess it would be filtering depending on the option the user chooses on the web page UI. I am going to just display back to the webpage

Comment: Without if else condition how will you filter data

Comment: I dont mind having if else, i am going to have about 10 different inputs so that will be an ton if if else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm looks for every property in `search` and if *all* comparisons are true, then the element is added to the result set.

```js
function filter(array, search) {
    return array.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(search).every(function (k) {
            return (
                a[k] === search[k] ||
                typeof search[k] === 'object' && +search[k].min <= a[k] &&  a[k] <= +search[k].max ||
                typeof search[k] === 'function' && search[k](a[k])
            );
        });
    });
}

var data = [{ name: "Michael", age: 30, bday: "05/12/1982" }, { name: "Andy", age: 30, bday: "02/21/1992" }, { name: "Justin", age: 19, bday: "12/07/1972" }];

// serach for name with n
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { name: function (s) { return s.match(/n/i); } }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// search for age = 30
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { age: 30 }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// search for age = 30 and bday = 02/21/1992
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { age: 30, bday: '02/21/1992' }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// search for age between 18 and 20
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { age: { min: 18, max: 20} }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have input for filtring information in ur HTML file

```
<input type="search" id="search" placeholder="search">
```

and JS file like this

```
$("#search").keyup(function () {
var searchField = $("#search").val();
// RegExp for case sensitive 
var myReg = new RegExp(searchField,"i");
$.getJSON('data.json',function (data) {
    var output ="<ul class='searchresults'>";
    $.each(data,function(key,val){
        if((val.name.search(myReg) != -1 ) || (val.info.search(myReg) != -1)){

            output +='<li>';
            output += "<h2>"+val.name+"</h2>";
            output += "<p>"+val.age+"</p>";
            output+='</li>';
        }
    });
    output +='</ul>';
    $("#update").html(output)
});
```

});